# How to edit product detail page in volusion

Tags: asp.net, volusion

As per client requirement we need to change designing of product detail page in volusion framework. I tried to find in admin panel (Top nav - Design -> File editor) but i am unable to find it. Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The company I work for has a Volusion site and after some research and contacting Volusion we were told that the code that runs the product detail page isn't accessible as it's shared by multiple stores. We made changes by replacing image files, making css changes and using javascript to add in functionality.

This particular page makes use of less than best paractices (at least in the template we were working with). There are a lot of nested tables that use 9 images to create borders and things like that that you'll have to contend with.

The image files are in a few different directories, but the majority are in wwwroot/v/vspfiles/templates/[your template]/images/. I used firebug to track them down and then ftp'ed new files in their place.

The css files are accessible in two ways:

- From the Top nav -  Design > File editor. Just click on the "Template
  [your template] css" link at the right of the page and then select the
  appropriate file from the dropdown.
- By ftp - wwwroot / v / vspfiles / templates / [your template] /
  css /

The .js files are accessible in two ways:

- From the Design > File Editor just click on the Directory after the
  template name in the "Choose File: wwwroot / v / vspfiles / templates
  / [your template]/" before the dropdown. Once the page reloads select
  "scripts" from the dropdown.
- By FTP - wwwroot / v / vspfiles / templates / [your template] /
  scripts /

Theoretically Volusion will automatically include any files in these directories, but you may want to add them to the template file. It's not the simplest way to change pages outside of the main template file but it does work.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i already found the answer but forgot to update in stackoverflow. Your answer is completely correct.